# Made a pow function for Array class in ruby, but doesnt return an array

Tags: ruby, oop

```
# Power Array
class Array
  def pow(power)
    map { |intgr| intgr**power.to_i }
  end
end

input, power = ARGV

if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
  exit
end

input = input.scan(/\d+/).map { |s| s.to_i }

puts input.pow(power)
```

command line arguments are passed and it works but output is not array.

expected : "[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]"

actual : "1\n8\n27\n64\n125\n216"

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "output is not array"? Which output do you mean? Are you talking about the return value of `Array#pow`? That most certainly *is* an `Array`. Are you talking about the stdout stream? That will never be an `Array`, you can't pass Ruby objects across to the shell, you can only pass ASCII text.

Comment: Is ASCII text for array is separated by \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between using `puts` and `p`.

The `puts` automatically adds a new line to the end of your message every time you use it and attempts to convert everything into a string (by calling `to_s`).

And `p` is a method that shows a more “raw” version of an object.

Example:

```
puts [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
=> "1\n8\n27\n64\n125\n216"

p [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
=> [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

More infos on [ruby doumentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-puts).

Comment: "automatically adds a new line" - it also has special handling for arrays.

Comment: Many Thanks, need to start doing basics

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way `puts` displays an array. Try `p` instead:

```
p input.pow(power)
```